# Using handlebars js, first form element not being created

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I made an article scraper using handlebars.  For each article link, I create a modal (using Bootstrap 4), however, the first modal generated for the first article doesn't generate the  element so, the notes for the first modal don't get posted since it has no reference to a POST route.

I'm not sure what the issue is.  Any input on what could be happening?

Here is my code below:

```
    {{#each article}}
        <div class="article">
            <h3>
                <a href="{{this.link}}" target="_blank">{{this.title}}</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn-default float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newNote{{this._id}}">Note</button>
            </h3>
        </div>
        {{/each}}


    <!-- Modal for NOTE -->
{{#each article}}
<div class="modal fade" id="newNote{{this._id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newAppt" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="welcome">Note for {{this.title}}</h1>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      {{!-- FORM HERE (doesn't generate for first modal created) --}}
        <form class="noteModal" action="/articles/{{this._id}}" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apptNotes">Notes</label>
            <textarea class="form-control placeholder" rows="5" id="apptNotes" name="body" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancelButton" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary regButton">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{{/each}}
```

Comment: It looks like you have an improper closing div tag below the form-group div.

Comment: I actually just found it.  I didn't have a closing </form> tag for a button in my header.  Thanks for the help!